# how to make this div draggable on chrome like on firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, draggable

this is the code:

```
<div contenteditable=true style="position:absolute;">dddw</div>
```

this code can be draggable on firefox , but cant on chrome ,

so how to make it draggable on chrome

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The resizing "handles" are managed differently so it will cause a noticeably different look between the browsers, however, you can get resize in Chrome using CSS3 resize attribute in combination with overflow:auto. (Firefox doesn't pick up on these, but its already being done by the ContentEditable as it adds a -moz-resizing="true" attribute to the element when it gets clicked.)

```
<div contenteditable=true style="resize:both;overflow:auto; position:absolute;">dddw</div>
```